# Hide comments and show them using views

Tags: 7, comments

Am using views to display the comments below my node types in drupal 7.

The view works fine but i can't find a way to hide the regular drupal comments above the form.

How do i just display the comment form and the comments using views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node.tpl

```
    hide($content['comments']);
```

This hides both the comment form and the comments.

To render the comment form alone use

```
    print render($content['comments']['comment_form']);
```

Then you can create your view for them nice comments and display them below the form.